# Polymorphism and overriding methods in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

I understand that polymorphism only applies to non-static and non-final methods of a class.

But take this example:

```
class Animal{
    public void play(){
        System.out.println("Play animal");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal{

    public void play(){
        System.out.println("Play dog");
    }

    public void bark(){
        System.out.println("Woof");
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        Animal d = new Dog();
        d.play(); //Outputs "Play dog"
        d.bark(); //ERROR
     }
}
```

I understand that d is a Dog object, and that every Dog *is a* Animal.

The program realises that d is a Dog object, and therefore calls the play() method from class Dog, **IGNORING** the fact that it's declared Animal.

But why, on the same principle, doesn't the program realise that d is a Dog object, **IGNORING** the Animal declaration?

This is the thing I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: Polymorphism happens at runtime, based on the actual concrete type of an object. The error you get happens at compile time, because the compiler won't let you call a method on a variable if that variable is of a *declared* type that doesn't have that method. Java wouldn't be a type-safe language if it let you do that. You would be able to call any method on any object, wouldn't get any help from the IDE, and would get a bunch of runtime errors because you tried to call an unexisting method.

Comment: @JBNizet I understand. That makes sense to me. Thank you very much.